# Manifold of entangled states

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given a specific density matrix $\rho$ that corresponds to an entangled quantum state, I would like to find a class of operators (that might be $\rho$ dependent) that tranform (with high probability) $\rho$ into other (possibly close) quantum states that have the same (or similar) entanglement. How can I characterize those operators?

Thank you

Fabio

Answer (score 3):

The entanglement of a density matrix $\rho$ is defined relative to a bipartition of the Hilbert space $H=H_A\otimes H_B$. This is invariant under local unitary operations, $\rho\mapsto U\rho U^\ast$ with $U=U_A\otimes U_B$ acting separately on $H_A$ and $H_B$.

More general entanglement preserving operations exist, see [Entanglement-Saving Channels](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00461) (2015).

Comment: That's what I thought, but it  seems not true. Meaning that given a separable state you cannot entangle it using local operations but given an entangled state you can destroy or decrease its entanglement with local operations.

Comment: not with local _unitary_ operations; these just amount to a change of basis, any meaningful measure of entanglement should be basis independent.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is simpler then what I thught then. Is this true even in the case of multipartite entanglement? So a entanglement preserving channel/operator can be always written as a convex combination of local unitaries (possibly random).

Comment: no, there exist more general entanglement-preserving channels, I added a reference.